# Solr-solj 6.5.0 in websphere 8 JDk

Tags: solr, solrj

In the eclipse, my jre System library is WebSphere 8 JDK, I have added following files to the library:

```
commons-io-2.5
httpclient-4.4.1
httpcore-4.4.1
httpmine-4.4.1
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7
noggit-0.6
slf4j-api-1.7.7
stax2-api-3.1.4
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1
zookeeper-3.4.6
solr-solrj-6.5.0
```

I have `import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;`, but the statement `SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();` still got error before I try to compile it. Can solr 6.5.0 run in WebSphere 8 JDK?

Comment: Which error? And are you trying to use the JDK with the Solr server, or just with the client libraries through SolrJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solr 6.5.0 is not supported java 1.6 JDk , it can not compile.